# Moving integers to the Stack in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

I'm learning to work with the Stack by trying to move integers to the Stack to then print them out in stdout. This is my code:

```
global _start

_start:

sub esp, 2
mov [esp], byte 1
mov [esp+1], byte 2

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, esp
mov edx, 2
int 0x80

mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 0x80
```

After executing, nothing seems to be printing out, as if I didn't even do a sys_write call. However, if the data I'm pushing to the Stack are characters, the code works properly and the characters do get printed out:

```
global _start

_start:

sub esp, 2
mov [esp], byte "N"
mov [esp+1], byte "o"

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, esp
mov edx, 2
int 0x80

mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 0x80
```

What's the reason for this? I suspected the issue was related to the data type I'm pushing to the Stack, so I tried writing other data sizes such as "word", instead of "byte", with no positive results. I also tried using the "push" commands instead of allocating the bytes manually by moving the Stack Pointer, with even more confusing results.

Comment: You're printing low-ASCII control characters. The system calls do not accept numeric inputs to format as numbers, all the bytes you write will be interpreted as text bytes. Format your numbers as text to make readable output.

Comment: Pipe it into `hexdump -C` to see the values of bytes your program writes to stdout, including ones that aren't printable ASCII codes like `"N"` (78)